# Creating a ZIP file from a string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, zip, nsfilemanager, ssziparchive

```
 let data = "InPractiseThisWillBeAReheallyLongString"
     
        createDir()
        
        let docsDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let ourDir = docsDir.appendingPathComponent("ourCustomDir/")
        let tempDir = ourDir.appendingPathComponent("temp/")
        let unzippedDir = tempDir.appendingPathComponent("unzippedDir/")
        let unzippedfileDir = unzippedDir.appendingPathComponent("unZipped.txt")
        let zippedDir = tempDir.appendingPathComponent("Zipped.zip")
        do {
            
            try data.write(to: unzippedfileDir, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
            
            
            let x = SSZipArchive.createZipFile(atPath: zippedDir.path, withContentsOfDirectory: unzippedfileDir.path)
            
            var zipData: NSData! = NSData()
            
            do {
                zipData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: unzippedfileDir.path, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
                //once I get a readable .zip file, I will be using this zipData in a multipart webservice
            }
            catch let err as NSError {
                print("err 1 here is :\(err.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        catch let err as NSError {
            
            print("err 3 here is :\(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

And the `createDir` function is:

```
func createDir() {
        let docsDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let ourDir = docsDir.appendingPathComponent("ourCustomDir/")
        let tempDir = ourDir.appendingPathComponent("temp/")
        let unzippedDir = tempDir.appendingPathComponent("unzippedDir/")
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: tempDir.path) {
            deleteFile(path: tempDir)
            deleteFile(path: unzippedDir)
        } else {
            print("file does not exist")
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: tempDir.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: unzippedDir.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                print("creating dir \(tempDir)")
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("here : " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Right now I am not getting any errors but when I download my appData container, get the ZIP file and attempt to unzip, I ma told the ZIP file is empty. I can see that the *unzipped.text* file does exist as expected.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Is there a method to create a `.zip` directly from the string without having to save the file to the data container?

---

#### UPDATE

I also tried the following and have the exact same results:

```
let zipArch = SSZipArchive(path: zippedDir.path)
        print(zipArch.open)
        print(zipArch.write(dataStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, filename: "blah.txt", withPassword: ""))
        print(zipArch.close)
```

Comment: `zipArch.write(dataStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, filename: "blah.txt", withPassword: nil)` is what you're looking for. Are you using latest version of SSZipArchive? You may want to raise bugs requests to https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive/issues

Answer (score 2):

I did it with ZipFoundation --> https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation

SWIFT

100% Working!!

1) Add ZipFoundation Framework to your project

2) Add import to your class

```
   import ZIPFoundation //Add to top of your class
```

Call Function

```
     zipString() . // Do your work
     extract(fileName: "myZip.zip") //Extract it to test it
     read(fileName : "zipTxt.txt" )  //Read you extracted File
```

Add function to your class

```
func zipString() {

    let zipName = "myZip.zip"
    let myTxtName = "zipTxt.txt"
    let myString = "I love to zip files"  // In your case "InPractiseThisWillBeAReheallyLongString"

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(zipName)

        //Create the zip file
        guard let archive = Archive(url: fileURL, accessMode: .create) else  {
            return
        }

       /* guard let archive = Archive(url: fileURL, accessMode: .update) else  {
            return
        } */ // In case you want to update

        print("CREATED")

         //Add file to
        let data = myString.data(using: .utf8)
        try? archive.addEntry(with: myTxtName, type: .file, uncompressedSize: UInt32(data!.count), compressionMethod: .deflate, provider: { (position, size) -> Data in

            return data!
        })

         print("ADDED")
    }

}
```

Bonus File Extraction

```
    /**
 ** Extract file for a given name
 **/
func extract(fileName : String){

    let fileManager = FileManager()
    let file = fileName
    // let currentWorkingPath = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)
        do {
            // try fileManager.createDirectory(at: dir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            try fileManager.unzipItem(at: fileURL, to: dir)
            print("EXTRACTED")

        } catch {
            print("Extraction of ZIP archive failed with error:\(error)")
        }

    }

}
```

For testing your extracted file

```
      func read(fileName : String){
    let file = fileName //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

        //reading
        do {
            let text2 = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
            print(text2)
        }
        catch {/* error handling here */}
    }
}
```

My Console Output...

CREATED

ADDED

EXTRACTED

I love to zip files

Comment: It works while zipping an individual file. Sadly while passing an entire directory as URL, it creates a corrupt .zip file that cannot be extracted.

Answer (score 2):

Little note: You can zip anything without using third party libraries ;)

```
/// Zip the itemAtURL (file or folder) into the destinationFolderURL with the given zipName
/// - Parameters:
///   - itemURL: File or folder to zip
///   - destinationFolderURL: destination folder
///   - zipName: zip file name
/// - Throws: Error in case of failure in generating or moving the zip
func zip(itemAtURL itemURL: URL, in destinationFolderURL: URL, zipName: String) throws {
    var error: NSError?
    var internalError: NSError?
    NSFileCoordinator().coordinate(readingItemAt: itemURL, options: [.forUploading], error: &error) { (zipUrl) in
        // zipUrl points to the zip file created by the coordinator
        // zipUrl is valid only until the end of this block, so we move the file to a temporary folder
        let finalUrl = destinationFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(zipName)
        do {
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: zipUrl, to: finalUrl)
        } catch let localError {
            internalError = localError as NSError
        }
    }
    
    if let error = error {
        throw error
    }
    if let internalError = internalError {
        throw internalError
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Kappe It rename the existing zip file if u added itemURL in zip

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ZIPFoundation](http://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation), which is another Swift ZIP library that allows you to read, create and modify ZIP files. One of its advantages is that it allows you to add ZIP entries "on-the-fly". You don't have to write your string to disk before creating an archive from it. It provides a closure based API where you can feed the string directly into a newly created archive:

```
func zipString() {
    let string = "InPractiseThisWillBeAReheallyLongString"
    var archiveURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
    archiveURL.appendPathComponent(ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString)
    archiveURL.appendPathExtension("zip")
    guard let data = string.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
    guard let archive = Archive(url: archiveURL, accessMode: .create) else { return }

    try? archive.addEntry(with: "unZipped.txt", type: .file, uncompressedSize: UInt32(data.count), provider: { (position, size) -> Data in
        return data
    })
}
```

The `addEntry` method also has an optional `bufferSize` parameter that can be used to perform chunked addition (so that you don't have to load the whole data object into RAM.)

Comment: Is it support multiple files zip? Thanks!